# Send email to all registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m kind of stuck and need some help!

I created a UserMailer and trying to pass a method  in which I can send an email to all registered users. I got it to send the email to all register users but cannot attach the subject and content. Both subject and content are created in the newsletter model with a form. If I try to pass this on the UserMailer  `mail to: emails, subject: newsletter.subject, content: newsletter.content` it returns an error.

If I leave it as bellow, it returns… `NoMethodError in Newsletters#deliver` … `undefined method 'subject'for nil:NilClass`  ….  in the view page.

Any ideas of what I might be missing? Thank you in advance!!

The model associations are:

user.rb has_many :newsletters

newsletter.rb belongs_to :user

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ‘example@gmail.com'

 def newsletter(users_email)
    @users = User.all
    emails = @users.collect(&:email).join(", ")
    mail(to: emails, subject: 'My Newsletter')
  end


class NewslettersController < InheritedResources::Base

    def deliver
     @newsletter = Newsletter.find params[:id]
     UserMailer.newsletter(@newsletter).deliver
     flash[:notice] = "Newsletter currently being delivered."
     redirect_to newsletters_url
   end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :newsletters do
    member do
      post :deliver 
  end
end
```

The link on the view page is `<%= link_to "Deliver", deliver_newsletter_path(newsletter), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :post %>`

And in the view page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Helo <%= @users.name %></h1>
    <p>
      Subject <%= @newsletter.subject %> <br>
    </p>

      <p>
      Subject <%= @newsletter.content %> <br>
     </p>
     <p>
     .<br>
     </p>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mailer you need to pass the `@newsletter` to the mailer view, just as from a controller to a regular view.

```
def newsletter(newsletter)
  @newsletter = newsletter
  @users = User.all
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple!!!Thank you @iceman!!! The only thing is that the user name does not appear on the email, I'm using this on the view page `<%= @users.name %>`... any ideas???

Comment: `@users` is an array of `Users`, so there is no name on that variable. Since you're sending the same email to all the users, as opposed to cycling thru the users list and send an individual email you cannot have the name in there.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your newsletter method. The argument is `users_email` is not being used.